# How do you make a computer with a new route stop using the old route's DNS?

Tags: windows-10, dns, routing, gateway

I have two NICs.  One is wireless, the other is Ethernet.  I removed the default gateway for the Ethernet,

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

I still have the wireless running.

However, the computer is trying to use the ethernet's DNS instead of the DNS the wireless is set to (and I verified with `ipconfig /all`.)

If I disable the hardware NIC, it will use the wireless DNS.  If I don't, even though I removed the onboard NIC as a default gateway, it uses the onboard NIC's DNS.  I have tried `ipconfig /flushdns`.

How do I force the machine to use the correct DNS, the one the Wireless uses?  I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Remove the DNS settings from the interface. Really this should t cause much trouble. Windows will try all the DNS servers until it gets a response.

Comment: How about manually configure the Ethernet adapter to have the same DNS IP as the wireless Adapter has?

Comment: Because they go do different networks.